# Txt to Docx, page orientation to horizontal

Tags: python, docx

In converting a text (.txt) file into a Word document (.docx), I try to set the page orientation to horizontal. However it is unsuccessful.

```
 from docx import Document
 from docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT
 from docx.shared import Pt

 fox = "C:\\temp\\lat.txt"
 # "there's only one lie in the text file"

 document = Document()

 sections = document.sections
 for section in sections:
     section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE

 style = document.styles['Normal']
 font = style.font
 font.size = Pt(25)

 with open(fox, encoding='utf-8') as f:
     for line in f:
         line = "\n".join(item for item in line.split('\n') if item)
         p = document.add_paragraph(line)

 document.save('C:\\temp\\lat-1.docx')
```

The generated .docx file is page vertical. What went wrong, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Enlightened by alexanderdamiani's answer on Github, (commented on Dec 1, 2017)
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/298

"The solution is you have to set the width and height after setting the orientation to landscape. So just grab the current width and height of the document, and then set them after changing the orientation."

To add below lines after above's "section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE".

```
new_width, new_height = section.page_height, section.page_width
section.page_width = new_width
section.page_height = new_height
```

Problem solved.